# Close ACTION_SENDTO intent if home button clicked

Tags: android, android-intent

My Android application have send email functionality. For this I'm using `ACTION_SENDTO` Intent. When I click 'Send E-Mail' button chooser is created and I'm clicking on some email client icon (Gmail for example). Message composer appears. After this I'm hitting home button and app closed and when I'm starting app again and I got email composer screen which is quite confusing because I want to start my app instead of email client.

Is it possible to close any `ACTION_SENDTO` activities if home button clicked?